# Rails 4 render action removing HTML from page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to render the results of a Python script in a rails app while also rendering HTML written in the `index.html.erb` file. I can render the HTML by redirecting to the `index.html.erb` file using the `redirect_to` command (commented out below since it throws an error when used with `render`). I am able to use the `render` command to render the result of the Python script. But I need to render both the HTML and the reulst. Here is the controller code:

```
class ContestsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
    @contest = Contest.new
  end

  def create
    @contest = Contest.new(contest_params)

    if contest_params[:contest_url] =~ /\A#{URI::regexp(['http', 'https'])}\z/
      if @contest.save
        value = %x(python test.py #{Shellwords.escape(contest_params[:contest_url])} 2>&1)
        render :text => value
        #redirect_to contests_url
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def contest_params
    params.require(:contest).permit(:contest_url)
  end
end
```

How can I render the HTML in `index.html.erb` and also render the result of the Python script (saved as `value` above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `render` two different things at the same time. Both `render` and `redirect_to` return content back to the requester. You can't return something to the requester twice.

What you can do is save the result of the Python script in a variable and pass that variable to one of your views as you render the view. Instance variables in controllers can be passed to ERB templates and rendered as HTML.

In your controller:

```
def create
  @contest = Contest.new(contest_params)

  if contest_params[:contest_url] =~ /\A#{URI::regexp(['http', 'https'])}\z/
    if @contest.save
      @value = %x(python test.py #{Shellwords.escape(contest_params[:contest_url])} 2>&1)
      render :index
    else
      render :new
    end
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

In your index.html.erb:

```
<p>Thanks for submitting! Here's the result of your Python script:</p>
<p><%= @value %></p>
```

I'm not 100% sure how you want to display this, but this is one solution.